# Is this session manager secure?

Tags: php, mysql, android, security

I'm looking for best practices for writing secure session managers.

I'm making a table for the authorization token (UUID OR GUIDv4) with autoincrement, user_id, token, status (enum) then update status onPause() onResume() so when I update a token I get a new autoincrement to store with the token in shared preference. Then on token update I just insert the old token with the user_id in another table for history.

The problems that I'm having:

1. it's good for a single device but when I want to update like password and update token I will have to end all user sessions and only the one I'm using will be updated.
2. should I add timestamp and keep the autoincrement inserted for a certain time of token updates or days or should I let it insert new autoincerment?

Is it good practice or there is a better way?

I already read about:

1. shared preference exploit on root.
   [Is Shared Preferences safe for private datas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34994807/6083675)
2. shared preference not secured even if I encrypt data.
   [Android SharedPreference security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244318/android-sharedpreference-security)
3. [ANDROID_ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) can be null and can change upon factory reset.
4. data will be not safe if sensitive data is exploited
   I came across this but could not find any other articles that approve the method he used [SQL injection](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection)

I already use a prepared statement:

```
<?php

$db_name = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABSE;charset=utf8";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
try {
    $PDO = new PDO($db_name, $db_username, $db_password);
    //echo "connection success";
} catch (PDOException $error) {
    //echo "Error: " . $error->getMessage();
    //echo "connection error";
    exit;
}
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("
                  SELECT
                  tableA.name AS name,
                  TABLEB.logo AS logo 
                  FROM tableA
                  LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.id = tableA.id 
                  WHERE tableA.id = :USERID ;
                    ");
$stmt->bindParam(':USERID', $user_id);

$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (!empty($user_id)) {
    $returnApp = new stdClass();
    $returnApp->LOADPROFILE = 'LOAD_SUCCESSFUL';
    $returnApp->LOAD_SUCCESSFUL = $row;
    echo json_encode($returnApp);
} else {
    $returnApp = array('LOADPROFILE' => 'LOAD_FAILED');
    echo json_encode($returnApp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see code for some of your items of concern, so I'll focus on reviewing the provided code.

- Your code should consistently respond with the same general formatted json string so that the receiving code can remain simple and elegant.  I think your business logic indicates that an empty array as a response is somehow a failure. A non-empty array will be success.
- You are not validating the submitted value.  If the submission is anything other than a positive integer, then you can safely give the failure response -- even before bothering with a database connection.
- I recommend eliminating single-use variables in any script unless they provide a valuable benefit.
- Unconditionally return the empty array or array of associative arrays that is provided by `fetchAll()`.

New code:

```
if (empty($_POST['user_id']) || !ctype_digit($_POST['user_id'])) {
    exit('[]');
}
$pdo = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABSE;charset=utf8",
    "root",
    ""
);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    "SELECT tableA.name AS name,
            TABLEB.logo AS logo 
     FROM tableA
     LEFT JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.id = tableA.id 
     WHERE tableA.id = ?"
);
$stmt->execute([$_POST['user_id']]);
echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

In terms of security, I am concerned about the fact that anyone can anonymously/trivially fire a bunch of integers at this code and get a direct feed of result set data.  Maybe this is why you mentioned UUIDs -- you might think that obscuring the identifier may improve security -- but it won't, it will only potentially slow down a persistent attacker.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't explain it well . i only provided a sample of how i usually get data because shared preference nothing i can do about it except I store a token(UUID) that changes instead of constant user_id . i miss typed the execution and fetch outside if condition and i only do this when i try to insert something and dont want the generate a row with empty variable so i choose random from all available .. thank you so much for updating my php.. if you can update with how often should i update token and if i should let it insert new autoincrement  with each update ill be very grateful

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question and show new, working code to be reviewed.  If you want behavior to be changed, we don't do this on CodeReview.

Comment: well that was my two problems and my only question was if doing that is a good practice to secure session manager you already gave an answer  that UUID will slow attacker but that wasnt the main problem

Comment: and android need result string to be able to switch between cases and then i get array + object so empty array is just a case i deal with on android side.. and i dont get what behavior to be change .. and what exactly you dont do on code review ??

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the Help pages on asking a question.

Comment: they only reason im gonna accept this answer because it gave me an idea of hashsalt the token ,update based on time and on that base i wont need autoincrement column which answer my questions ABOVE ..guess that would work with validating the submitted value before connecting to database .. next time i hope you really read the question carefully before assuming you already answered it and maybe you can check tour which STATE that i can use comment to clarify the problem no just asking unnecessary new questions

Comment: Just to be clear, on CodeReview, we are only permitted to review posted code.  I reviewed the only code posted.  I am confident that this does not make me a bad reviewer.

Comment: @mickmacusa im not saying that you are a bad reviewer .. im pretty confident that anyone with a good reputation score would help me improve my code and gain knowledge from specially that im self learning and i love it ..that "If you want behavior to be changed, we don't do this on CodeReview."  what i found really unnecessary .. its my first use of codereview and it was recommened by another user on stackoverflow but didnt tell me much about codereview

Comment: one last thing .. im proud to say that this community have helped me ALOT even on naive question or errors